# Should I handle ajax requests in vanilla Django or rest Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a bunch of ajax requests on my website (ex. upvote sends request to server)

Should I integrate this functionality server side just with another view function

Or is it recommended that I shove all the necessary views into a Django rest framework?

Comment: you can write n number of ajax requests in the server, make it ajax.py instead normal views.py then root the ajax functions in the urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually follow DDD approach. So all my requests end up being just a CRUD operation for an entity. I always prefer REST APIs, thus I would say if you have DDD approach already in place go with django-rest-framework.

Otherwise, it really does not matter, depends on your need.